# Resources Available But System Slowing Down

Tags: computer-building, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 installed. The system is completely slowed even though CPU usage is sitting less than 15% and Memory averages out at 50-60%. No malware or virus advice required. System is running Avira and only trusted software is installed after scanning through VirusTotal. CPU temp. is just 45*C. No 3rd party background processes. I just need a small reason to upgrade my hardware. When so much resources are available, why windows even takes time to open even my browser?

Comment: Note - Real time malware scanning is turned off and is not an issue.

Comment: Have you checked your hard drive for S.M.A.R.T. errors? Have you run a Memtest?

Comment: @spikey_richie There are no S.M.A.R.T errors. Although WIndows memory diagnostic found some bad pages in my RAM and and got a warning to replace it? Is the issue this much?

Comment: Seems likely. Bad RAM can manifest itself in many different ways.